# no tag was defined for name: viewAction

Tags: jsf-2

I have just incorporated JSF 2.2.2 in my existing project and I want to use `f:viewAction` but I am getting the following error.

```
<f:viewAction> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core, \
but no tag was defined for name: viewAction
```

Here is my code:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{testBean.doIT}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Here is my controller:

```
@Named("testBean")
@Scope(ScopeType.VIEW)
public class TestBeanimplements Serializable {
public void doIT(){
  System.out.println("Test Working !!!!!!!!");
    }
}
```

Here is my maven configuration for JSF:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Could anyone please explain to me why I am getting this error ?

Comment: You should accept the answer if it worked for you (does not work for me though)

Comment: Also please add your server (glassfish ? Jboss?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use the new namespace:  `xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"`

Comment: Getting: `Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core declared with prefix f but no taglibrary exists for that namespace` - JBoss AS 7.2

Comment: If you are getting XML namespace warning and working on Eclipse, rebuild your project and restart Eclipse.

Comment: In my case it was a problem of mixed Mojarra versions on the classpath.