# Accessing query-string parameters in a post construct method in a view scoped managed bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I have the following XHTML page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </h:head>

    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{testManagedBean.id}" maxlength="20"/>
    </f:metadata>

    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form" prependId="true">

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The managed bean corresponds to the above JSF page.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class TestManagedBean implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        System.out.println("id = "+id);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I'm passing `id` as a query-string parameter using the URL - `https://localhost:8181/Project-war/admin_side/Test.jsf?id=1`.

Trying to display `id` in the `init()` method is always `null`.

This is a demonstration. In reality, `<f:viewParam>` is actually put inside `<ui:define name="metaData">` and on the master template `<ui:insert name="metaData"/>` is defined.

What am I overlooking here?

<sub>I have several times passed such parameters and converted to a JPA entity using appropriate converters but I don't know why a scalar value is not being set to a property of a managed bean. I have tried changing the type of `id` to String but that also did not help either (nor `@ManagedProperty(value="#{id}")` worked).</sub>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10261453, http://stackoverflow.com/q/9844526, http://stackoverflow.com/q/6377798

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `f:viewParam` is not available during `@PostConstruct`. Use `f:viewAction` instead.

[See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id)

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)

Comment: In which namespace was `<f:viewAction>` defined? It is not available in `http://java.sun.com/jsf/core`. This namespace `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core` as stated by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18352652/1391249) answer is also not available. It gives an error, `No library found for namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core`. I'm using Mojarra 2.2.6.

Comment: The namespaces like `http://xmlns.jcp.org/...` became available only when I upgraded the NetBeans IDE from [7.2.1](https://netbeans.org/downloads/7.2.1/) to the latest release [8.0](https://netbeans.org/downloads/). Like Eclipse, It was a [quirk](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=228064) in NetBeans.